# Getting Json Response Api

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I created an authentication API (Login and Sign up) using larval and I tested them in android studio and they are working well, during connection I get all the information of the user.

> I/onSuccess: {"status":"success","data":{"id":2,"name":"user","prenom":"user"...}

My Login fragment

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(LoginInterface.LOGINURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            LoginInterface api = retrofit.create(LoginInterface.class);

            Call<String> call = api.getUserLogin(getEmailId, getPassword);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                            Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());

                            String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);

                                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    Intent intent;
                                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityListEvents.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
```

My Login Interface

```
public interface LoginInterface {

    String LOGINURL = "http://192.168.1.105/AnnocesPFE/public/api/";
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<String> getUserLogin(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password
    );

}
```

I need to get the Id from the login fragment and use it into my profil fragment how can i do it ?

I need to use it in ProfileFragment

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(UpdateProfile.UPDPRO)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        UpdateProfile api = retrofit.create(UpdateProfile.class);
        Call<String> call = api.UpdateUsers(getId(),name,prenom,adresse,email,numtel);
        //Log.i("updateUsers: ",prenom);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                        Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());
                        String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);

                            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            } else if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("error")) {
                              /*  new CustomToast().Show_Toast(getActivity(), view,
                                        " " + jsonObject.getString("message"));*/
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the response you get from your authentication API into a JSONObject and then get the values you need.

For example,

```
JSONObject authenticationData = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
try {
   int successId = authenticationData.getInt("id");
catch(JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can pass along the successId to the fragment of your choice.

Read more about [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject)

If you meant how to pass data between fragments, then please show us the structure and some code.

Answer (score 0):

My login interface

```
 public interface LoginInterface {
    String LOGINURL = "http://192.168.1.108/AnnocesPFE/public/api/";
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<String> getUserLogin(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password
    );
}
```

LoginFragment

```
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(LoginInterface.LOGINURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            LoginInterface api = retrofit.create(LoginInterface.class);

            Call<String> call = api.getUserLogin(getEmailId, getPassword);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                            Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());

                            String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);

                                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                    Intent intent;
                                    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityListEvents.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
```

When i login i got the response in my console

> I/onSuccess: {"status":"success","data":{"id":2,"name":"user","prenom":"user"...}

My update profile interface

```
public interface UpdateProfile {

    String UPDPRO ="http://192.168.1.108/AnnocesPFE/public/api/";
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @PUT("users/{id}")
    Call<String> UpdateUsers(
            @Path("id") int id,
            @Field("name") String name,
            @Field("prenom") String prenom,
            @Field("adresse") String adresse,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("numtel") String numtel
    );
}
```

ProfileFragment

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(UpdateProfile.UPDPRO)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        UpdateProfile api = retrofit.create(UpdateProfile.class);
        Call<String> call = api.UpdateUsers(getId(),name,prenom,adresse,email,numtel);
        Log.i("updateUsers: ",String.valueOf(getId()));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.i("Responsestring", response.body().toString());
                        Log.i("onSuccess", response.body().toString());
                        String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonresponse);

                            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            } else if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("error")) {
                              /*  new CustomToast().Show_Toast(getActivity(), view,
                                        " " + jsonObject.getString("message"));*/
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Update failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }
```

getID() retrun an false value i need to have the id of current user connected to use it in my profile fragment